# Laravel array validation nullifying values

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to validate the values of an array of objects in Laravel which I pass through the request from the client side (encoded).

First of all, I decode the values passed through the request then validate to check it is null or not.

This is my code

```
$request->request->set('shopping_list', array_map(function ($arr) {
    return json_decode($arr);
}, $request->shopping));

$validator = Validator::make($request->toArray(), [
    'shopping_list' => ['required'],
    'shopping_list.*' => ['required'],
    'shopping_list.*.store' => ['required'],
    'shopping_list.*.item' => ['required'],
    'shopping_list.*.quantity' => ['required'],
    'shopping_list.*.brand' => ['required'],
    'shopping_list.*.size' => ['required'],
]);

if (count($validator->errors()) > 0) {
    return Response::json($validator->errors()->first(), 422);
}
```

Unexpectedly the server is returning no error messages. When I return `$request->all()` or `$request->toArray()`, after the validation has been done, I am getting the values as follow

[image: Nullified Response]

If I return it before the validation takes place, I am getting a response like this

[image: Response from the server]

How can I fix this issue and validate the items?

Comment: Have you tried `['required', 'string']` validation rules?

Comment: @thefallen Tried. Still the same issue :(

Comment: Your input is not an array, it is a JSON string. I'm not sure of Laravel by default casts the JSON string to an array then runs the validation or not but that is your issue.

Comment: @Script47 But I am encoding it to an array. Even if it is not an array the validator should return an error message.

Comment: @Conor and if you did `return json_decode($arr, true);`, does it work?

Comment: @Script47 Thanks a lot friend. It worked. But why? The result is the same. And I suppose `json_decode()` does convert the array to an associated array by default.

Comment: @Conor I've posted an answer, maybe that'll clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my suggestion, when using `json_decode` you can force the JSON string to be returned as associative array by passing `true` as the second parameter. You were trying to run the validation flags built for arrays on objects.

**Note:** `toArray` doesn't convert your JSON to arrays or objects, it simply converts all the properties passed from an object (`$request->my_input`) to an assoc array.

Answer (score 0):

As a "not good advise". You can call `$request->toArray()` (and save data in in some variable) before `Validator::make(...`.

Comment: That is not making any difference in the output.